# create a function using while loop

Tags: python, function, while-loop, spyder

How can i add the travel fare into a while loop (error message) that works with many travel fares? I want to create a function using the while loop. like without inserting the error message after each travelFare, i want to create a function to stop myself from repeating. and my using spyder.

```
travelfare1=float(input("enter travel fare 1:" ))

travelfare2=float(input("enter travel fare 2: "))

travelfare3=float(input("enter travel fare 3: "))

while travelfare1 <5 or travelfare1 >20:

    print("invalid entry")

    travelfare1=float(input("enter travel fare 1:" ))
```

please help

Comment: that makes little sense, but, are you trying to properly query correct values from a user within a range for each variable with a function?

Comment: I want to prevent the user from inserting a higher or low value. should i create a list for the travel fare? would that be easier to combine with a function? im very new python and coding im really confuse where to insert what!!

Comment: yes, it might be better to store multiple values like that in a list, you could easily iterate with an input function to go way over your 3 variables :)

Comment: do you only want values within 5 and 20 or do you want to **exclude** values in that range?

Comment: only the values within 5 and 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out:

```
def get_fare(mini, maxi):
    fare = float(input("travel fare please: "))
    while fare not in range(mini, maxi+1):
        print("invalid value, please enter a new one") 
        fare = float(input("travel fare please: "))
    return fare

travel_fares = [get_fare(5,20), get_fare(5,20), get_fare(5,20)] # list of the functions (which will make a list of the return values after they're run)

print(f"average: {sum(travel_fares)/len(travel_fares)}") # sum of elements in list divided by length of list (amount of items)
```

when entering: `15`, `10` and `5`:

```
travel fare please: 5
travel fare please: 10
travel fare please: 15
average: 10
```

Comment: I think the 20 and 5 are backwards. This is a good approach, although I didn't add the array in my answer since it wasn't specified in the question.

Comment: ugh its late my brain isnt working. that should fix it, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
def get_travel_fare(number):
    travelfare = float(input(f"enter travel fare {number}:" ))
    while travelfare < 5 or travelfare > 20:

        print("invalid entry")

        travelfare = float(input(f"enter travel fare {number}:" ))
    return travelfare


travelfare1 = get_travel_fare(1)
travelfare2 = get_travel_fare(2)
travelfare3 = get_travel_fare(3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! it worked but i ran into a new issue, would you be able to help? i I have to Calculate the Average and i used this formula,   travelfareavareage= (travelfare1 +travelfare2+travelfare3)
 but i got this error
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Comment: state the issue ^

Comment: i I have to Calculate the Average and i used this formula, travelfareavareage= (travelfare1 +travelfare2+travelfare3) but i got this error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Comment: @rara if this answer helped you can accept it with the green check. That error you have sounds like one of the numbers wasn't entered correctly, have you tried printing out each of the travelfares to see what they are?

Comment: i ran it few times.first i used all 20s and then I used numbers that are bellow 20.  should I use the travelfare1 or get_travel_fare(1) in order to calculate? I'm sorry if I'm sounding dumb.

Comment: @rara I added `print((travelfare1+travelfare2+travelfare3)/3)` after that and it printed the average correctly. Does this work for you?

Comment: I got it. i had a wrong indentation somewhere. thank you so much for your help:)